# How to fetch images from computer folder?

Tags: android

The images are stored in folder.how to fetch that images.

I have already tried below code:

```
File imgFile = new File("/home/gwtttt/hor/cimg.png");



if(imgFile.exists()) {


        Log.e("imagefile", "" + imgFile.exists());
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/home/gwtttt/hor/cimg.png");
        Log.e("mybitmapee",""+myBitmap);
        //im.setImageResource(myBitmap);
        Log.e("path", "" + myBitmap);
        im.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
        }
```

but output is show the blank window.

please help me............

thank in advance........

Comment: How can you access gallery of your friends device ? does your system and mobile ever same?

Answer (score 1):

There are ~1.5 billion Android devices. Fortunately for you, none of them have direct access to your computer, for obvious privacy and security reasons.

If you want to show an image in an Android app, you have to get that image to the Android device, such as by packaging it as a drawable resource in the app, or by downloading it from a Web server. Your computer could host a Web server that the Android app accesses, for example.

Answer (score 0):

put cimg.png file in drawable folder and write down below code in your main file 
you can use mipmap folder too.

```
im.setImageResource(R.drawable.cimg);
```